# How to read and write data concurrently in Python?

Tags: python

Hi Guys I am looking for the optimized approach for my below requirement.

I am trying to write data into a file based on the output from a db table getting thru the ODBC connection(from Vertica). But we have specified a limit on number of lines that a file can contain at max. If the file has more number of rows than specified then it has to create a new file with the remaining data.

I am not sure which approach (below specified) will be good for my requirement.

1. First I will write all the data into a single file and then based on the number of line limits specified in the config, I will split the file. (Or)
2. I will just make a counter to count number of lines writing to the file and if the counter is exceeding the file line limit then will create another file with remaining data.

Note: I have more than 500 million rows in my table.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: You're not going to want to do that. IO is pretty notoriously serial.

Comment: If you are able to write the data into a single file... Why would you need to split it up?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen _But we have specified a limit on number of lines that a file can contain at max._

Comment: Yes I am bale to generate the file into a single file but I need to upload the generated the file to some sftp and if the size of the generated file is so huge then the network has some issue. That's why I am generating file in smaller piece so that we can upload into sftp without hiccups.

Comment: @erip yes I see that but usually a size limit is implemented when the server cannot store the entire data in a single file, so if the OP is able to use a single file without network issues I don't see the point of splitting it up, why is there a maximum number of lines if filesize is not an issue?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen We don't know. I presume it's non-negotiable, so I don't worry about it. :D